# how to i call parse expression method in my jax-rs

Tags: java, client, jax-rs, expression, calculator

how do i call the parse Expression method in my JAX-RS @post method that accepts a string from a client. i have no idea how to go about doing this so any help or examples that might work would be much appreciated 
code to help with more string of operations

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ExpressionParser {

```
public static final Pattern SPLIT_REGEX = Pattern.compile("(?:([-]?\\d+)([-+/*=])?)");

public long parseExpression(String expression) {
    long left = 0;
    char operator = '+';
    Matcher m = SPLIT_REGEX.matcher(expression);
    while (m.find()) {
        String operand = "";
        try {
            operand = m.group(1);
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            operand = "0";
        }
        left = calculate(left, operator, Long.valueOf(operand));

        String oper = m.group(2);
        if (oper != null)
            operator = oper.charAt(0);

    }
    return left;
}

private long calculate(long left, char operator, long right) {
    switch (operator) {
    case '+':
        return left + right;
    case '-':
        return left - right;
    case '*':
        return left * right;
    case '/':
        return left / right;
    case '=':
        return left;
    default:
        return 0L;
    }
}
```

}

my jax-rs code

@Path("calculate")
public class Calculator {

```
private final Long value;

public Calculator() {
    value = 0L;
}

public Calculator(Long initialValue) {
    this.value = initialValue;
}

@GET
public Long getValue() {
    return value;
}

@Path("add/{value1}/{value2}")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Long add(@PathParam("value1") Long value, @PathParam("value2") Long value2) {
    return value + value2;
}
@Path("subtract/{value1}/{value2}")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Long subtract(@PathParam("value1") Long value, @PathParam("value2") Long value2) {
    return value - value2;
}
@Path("multipli/{value1}/{value2}")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Long multipli(@PathParam("value1") Long value, @PathParam("value2") Long value2) {
    return value * value2;
}
@Path("divide/{value1}/{value2}")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Long divide(@PathParam("value1") Long value, @PathParam("value2") Long value2) {
    return value / value2;
}
```

}

Comment: 1) You don't have a @POST method. 2) What exactly is the problem? Do you not know how to call a method in a different class? This seems more like a basic Java question that has nothing to do with JAX-RS.

Comment: There's to sets of code above public calss expressionparse and public class calculator. The top code is what I want to use as a calculator as an update to the bottom code which contains no JAX-RS . Or should I be using both classes to preform simple calculations for my client side ?